# A more polite expression than "minor languages"

Tags: politeness, register, synonyms

I am translating a text to English for a university describing a program aimed at multicultural literacy:

> Students acquire minor languages in addition to English.

The above translation is no doubt correct, but is there a more tactful way to indicate "minor languages"? It seems that calling them "minor" could be taken as a value judgement.

I have been given "Mongolian" as an example of a "minor language".

Any alternate wordings would be appreciated.

Comment: Are they really calling them *minor languages* or do the students graduate with a *minor* in one or more languages in addition to their *major*?

Comment: Why is it necessary to comment on the languages? It's much more useful to give a list. If anybody actually **wants** to learn one of those languages, they may not be thrilled by them getting dissed by the multicultural literacy folks.

Comment: Are all non-English languages "minor languages" in this context?

Comment: These are valid questions! @Jim, these are not related to concentration. "Minor" here is used to indicate relative language usage in the world.

Comment: @JohnLawler, space is at a premium, so an exhaustive list would be untenable.

Comment: @sumelic, that is not clear. The examples I was given were those that are used in relatively small populations, such as Mongolian. (I have updated my question to reflect this.)

Comment: Students acquire fluency in one or more languages in addition to English.

Comment: I think 'impolite' is way too strong. 'deprecatory' might be too strong. The first thing that comes to mind is 'secondary'. But if minor is not liked then one might still not like 'secondary'. It'll be difficult to get a single common word to capture what you want exactly ('lower incidence' is accurate but a bit of a mouthful).

Answer (score 1):

Here in New York City, exams are translated into Spanish and five other languages. All others are called **lower incidence languages**.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might be talking about [minority languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minority_language). Mongolian isn't a minority language in Mongolia, but there are Mongolian-speaking language minorities in China and elsewhere.